# Como cambio el valor de una llave dentro de un diccionario dentro de una función

Tags: python, game

Estoy haciendo una especie de juego para un proyecto, y quiero mostrar las habilidades del jugador, al igual que dejarlo subir de nivel de acuerdo a lo que quiere hacer el jugador. El problema que tengo es que al aumentar el nivel (en el if más alejado), no se mantiene el valor dentro de la función Start(). Quisiera saber si hay una forma que no involucre usar muchos elif.

```
global nivel, MP, fuerza, agilidad, percepcion, inteligencia, vitalidad, puntos, stats
nivel = 1
puntos = 0
vida = 50
MP = 25
vitalidad = 1
fuerza = 1
agilidad = 1
percepcion = 1
inteligencia = 1


# Esta función te dá las estadísticas de tu personaje para que puedas ver la mejor estrategia de qué usar
def Stats(vitalidad, fuerza, agilidad, percepcion, inteligencia):
    stats = {"NIVEL: ": nivel, "VIDA: ": int(vitalidad * 1.2 + 49), "MAGIA: ": int(inteligencia * 1.2 + 49), "VITALIDAD: ": vitalidad, "FUERZA: ": fuerza, "AGILIDAD: ": agilidad, "PERCEPCIÓN: ": percepcion, "INTELIGENCIA: ": inteligencia}
    for x in stats:
        print(x, end="")
        print(stats[x])
    print("\n")
    return stats
            
def subir_de_nivel(nivel, puntos, fuerza):
    nivel += 1
    puntos += 5
    while puntos > 0:
        print("Puntos disponibles: %i \n" % puntos)
        a = Stats(nivel, vitalidad, fuerza, agilidad, percepcion, inteligencia)
        lugar = str(input("Donde quieres colocar tus puntos de habilidad: ")).upper()
        if lugar != "NIVEL" and lugar == "FUERZA" or lugar == "MAGIA" or lugar == "VITALIDAD" or lugar == "AGILIDAD" or lugar == "PERCEPCION" or lugar == "INTELIGENCIA":
            for i in a:
                if (lugar + ": ") == i:
                    subir = int(input("Cuantos puntos quieres meter en %s" % i))
                    if subir <= puntos:
                        a[lugar + ": "] += subir
                        puntos -= subir
                        print("Puntos sobrantes: %i \n" % puntos)
                        print(lugar + ": ", a[lugar + ": "], "\n")
                    else:
                        print("Puntos insuficientes")
        else:
            print("ERROR: Opción inválida.\nTiene que ser una estadística, nivel, vida o magia no son elegibles")
```